# .NET: Start a thread as suspended

Tags: .net, multithreading

In unmanaged code you can create a thread in suspended state. In .NET Framework I can't find this option. Is it because the Thread constructor puts the thread in a suspended state? Is there other reason why this is not supported?

Comment: just to be curious? what's the use for this?

Comment: I wanted to start a couple of threads at once. I know I can do that with ManualResetevent. Another solution which can work on unmanaged is to create the threads as suspended and then resume them.

Comment: You should know that there's no way to guarantee that the threads will start at *exactly* the same time, not even with a `ManualResetEvent`.  Starting several threads as suspended and then resuming them would be functionally equivalent to calling `Thread.Start` on several unstarted threads; both have equal chance of starting at roughly the same time.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I know that they will not start exactly at the same time. It is just an estimation for a tester I am trying to write.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a new `Thread`, its `ThreadState` is `ThreadState.Unstarted`, not `ThreadState.Suspended`.

This *may* correspond to a suspended thread at the OS level; however, the implementation details of a managed thread are something you should not be concerning yourself with.  .NET threads are more than just simple wrappers around unmanaged threads.

You may also note that the `Suspend` and `Resume` methods of the `Thread` class are marked as **obsolete**, with this [scary warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx):

> Do not use the Suspend and [Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resume.aspx) methods to synchronize the activities of threads. You have no way of knowing what code a thread is executing when you suspend it. If you suspend a thread while it holds locks during a security permission evaluation, other threads in the [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) might be blocked. If you suspend a thread while it is executing a class constructor, other threads in the [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) that attempt to use that class are blocked. Deadlocks can occur very easily.

Directly suspending and resuming threads is highly discouraged in .NET, and if you started a thread "as suspended", then you would have to `Resume` it.  They want to discourage people from using *any* of these methods, so instead they use the special `Unstarted` status and get you to `Start` the thread instead of `Resuming` it.  It's a much cleaner abstraction anyway.

Summary: The option is not directly available to you because you are not supposed to be suspending **or** resuming threads at all - leave that up to the .NET runtime, or even better, use the `ThreadPool` when you can.